# aws ec2i have multiple intances place behind the elb in aws i want tp make communication from different server like if

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have multiple instances placed behind the elb in aws I want to make communication from the different servers like if they are in a private subnet I can give a third party a nat gateway ip to whitelist but if I have ec2 in public subnet then what to give them I have multiple intances. so I give one ip ?/